# Django urls multiple parameters matching to wrong pattern

Tags: django, url, django-urls, url-parameters

My goal is to create a url structure where simply inputting `mywebsite.com/apple/` would return `c_one`, and inputting `mywebsite.com/apple/homepage` would return `c_two` with `company=apple` and `pagetype=homepage`.

However, the url `mywebsite.com/apple/homepage` is returning `c_one` and considers company to be "apple/homepage".

My code is below, let me know if there is any way around this issue for urls to realize that there are two variables if a slash is used. Thank you!

```
url(r'^c/(?P<company>[\w|\W]+)/$', views.c_one, name='c_one'),
url(r'^c/(?P<company>[\w|\W]+)/(?P<pagetype>[\w|\W]+)/$', views.c_two, name='c_two'),
url(r'^c/(?P<company>[\w|\W]+)/(?P<pagetype>[\w|\W]+)/(?P<topic>[\w|\W]+)/$', views.c_three, name='c_three')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in your definition of the patterns.

With using both, `\w` and `\W` you're basically saying *any given character*.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) the definition of `\w` is `[A-Za-z0-9_]` and the definition of `\W` is `[^A-Za-z0-9_]`. Basically `\W` is the complement of `\w`, so you're matching any character.

Modify your config like this and it should work:

```
url(r'^c/(?P<company>\w+)/$', views.c_one, name='c_one'),
url(r'^c/(?P<company>\w+)/(?P<pagetype>\w+)/$', views.c_two, name='c_two'),
url(r'^c/(?P<company>\w+)/(?P<pagetype>\w+)/(?P<topic>\w+)/$', views.c_three, name='c_three')
```